# Skip a line in csv line when an error occours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that I want to turn into a DataFrame, but some of the lines have formating errors like:

A normal line: `22.02.2023,13:42:01,0.4373,2.5729,687.3574`

An unusual line:

`0.0011, 12:42:01, 0.0021, 3.9782, 0.0001` or `22.02.2023999,13:42:010.4373,2.5729,687.3574444`

Keep in min that the formating errors are not always the same and may vary in its location in the line. The code needs to be able to skip the malformated line everytime the error occours.

I am using `pd.read_csv(csv_file, on_bad_lines='skip')` to do the job, which works perfecly when the file formating is good.

Comment: First you would need to define what counts as a "formatting error".

Comment: `pd.read_csv` won't be able to do what you're looking for since those lines are not an issue for it. By the documentation, `on_badline` `Specifies what to do upon encountering a bad line (a line with too many fields)` . Your examples don't show having too many fields. If you want to handle those lines, for the second case, where the delim goes missing, you can use `dataframe.dropna(axis=0)` since it will likely leave a `nan` value in the row, the first will likely need you to do processing on the dataframe itself based on how you define the formatting error.